# HTTP Request to Edit Database

Tags: php, mysql, http

I am trying to use a MySQL database to verify that a user has bought a program from my site. I don't need to use a database, but this is the easiest way that I though this could be accomplished (any suggestions on different ways to accomplish a purchase-verification system are greatly appreciated).

My current algorithm:

1. User pays for the program (through one of various payment gateways provided by WooCommerce)
2. User is given a unique, randomized hex string by the server (this string is also stored in the database, as a key/value pair; string: 0; the 0 signifies unused)
3. User enters the string into the program (required), which sends an HTTP request (which includes the string) to the server. This request tells the server to look for the given string in the database. If it's found, change it's value to 1 (used). If the value is already 1 OR the string cannot be found, send an error report back to the user (program will not work).
4. If everything works correctly, the user can now use the program.

I have to use the HTTP request because only the server can edit the database. My website uses shared hosting, so I cannot directly modify the database on any local user.

I've never worked with databases before, but I know I have to use the `INSERT`, `CREATE TABLE`, `UPDATE`, and `SELECT` commands. In addition, I've never directly worked with HTTP requests.

How should the HTTP request look like, and how do I handle them on the server? Any other tips on how to work the database would also be appreciated.

Note: I'm probably going to use PHP (server-side) and Python (client-side).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your html would look like this

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="validate.php" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
unique string: <input type="text" name="uniqueString"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

And on the server side, your validate.php would look like this.

```
<?php


  $name = $_POST["name"];
  $unqString = $_POST["uniqueString"];

//connect to your DB
mysql_connect("your.hostaddress.com", "username", "password") or die(mysql_error()); 
mysql_select_db("Database_Name") or die(mysql_error()); 
$data = mysql_query("SELECT uniqueStringUsedFlag FROM <stringTableName> WHERE uniqueString='.$unqString.'") 
 or die(mysql_error()); 

while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) {
  if $info['uniqueStringUsedFlag']==1{
    return 'Error Message';
}else
{

mysql_query("update <stringTableName> set uniqueStringUsedFlag =1 where uniqueString='.$unqString.'");   

return 'Success';

}
}

//if the control comes here, it means the record was not found.
return 'Error message'


?>
```

Replace < stringTableName > with your actual table name.
And do the same with the columns too.
PS: This code is untested. And please do proper validations, etc. Haven't included that here.
Let me know if this works.

Comment: Thanks! I need to get the validation string through an HTTP request though, because the string has to be entered locally (from a program). I know how to send the request, just not how to "access" it from PHP.

Comment: $unqString = $_POST["uniqueString"];   is accessing the data sent from client in the server. Is this what you meant when you said extracting?